# Cygwin: problems installing Seismic Unix - error part way through install

Tags: software-installation, cygwin

I'm in need of some advice installing 'Seismic Unix' in Cygwin for windows 10. Hopefully someone who has done this before can help me.

The problem I have is when I run `make install` the install process runs to a point, then exits with an error. Seems to happen when the program ties to run the makefile in:

```
.....\cwp_su_all_44R19\src\su\main\filters
```

The error output is:

```
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/USER/cwp_su_all_44R19/src/su/main/dip_moveout'
cd filters ; make
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/USER/cwp_su_all_44R19/src/su/main/filters'
gcc -I/home/USER/cwp_su_all_44R19/include -O  -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long   -DCWP_LITTLE_ENDIAN   -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE sulfaf.c  -L/home/USER/cwp_su_all_44R19/lib -lsu -lpar -lcwp -lm  -o /home/USER/cwp_su_all_44R19/bin/sulfaf
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /home/USER/cwp_su_all_44R19/lib/libsu.a(fputgthr.o):fputgthr.c:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `tr'; /home/USER/cwp_su_all_44R19/lib/libsu.a(fgetgthr.o):fgetgthr.c:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: [Makefile:35: /home/USER/cwp_su_all_44R19/bin/sulfaf] Error 1 (ignored)
chmod: cannot access '/home/USER/cwp_su_all_44R19/bin/sulfaf': No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [Makefile:36: /home/USER/cwp_su_all_44R19/bin/sulfaf] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/USER/cwp_su_all_44R19/src/su/main/filters'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:14: INSTALL] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/USER/cwp_su_all_44R19/src/su/main'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:8: INSTALL] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/USER/cwp_su_all_44R19/src/su'
```

I've tried installing a few different versions of SU, but I run into exactly the same problem. Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you say you have tried "a few different versions", would you mind editing your question to include which ones?

Comment: Sure! so far I've tried cwp_su_all_44R19 and ....._44r18. both downloaded from here: https://nextcloud.seismic-unix.org/index.php/s/LZpzc8jMzbWG9BZ. With both versions I get exactly the same problem, the install runs fine until it gets to making the files .exe files in ....cygwin\home\USER\cwp_su_all_44R19\src\su\main\filters, then i get the error message about multiple definition of 'tr'.   'tr' is an executable located in cygwin\bin (i believe)

Comment: Ever get an answer? - I am getting the same problem. I have been editing the make files to delete the offending utilities. Of course, I miss out on some software.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc
```

to your linker flags in the Makefile in the affected folder

It's not elegant, but it solves the problem.